# How to prevent JS plugin acting on html anchors from jumping to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So [here's my friend's page that he's working on](http://acsweb.ucsd.edu/~anislam/) and he's using some plugin called Flip Lightbox (he only was able to give me a minified version of the javascript, making this a lot harder) and if you visit the site you can see that the basic functionality is that you click on any of the images, and the image flips over and comes out as a lightbox. This works fine, however when you go farther down the page and click the images towards the bottom, the lightbox still works but clicking anything will immediately jump to the top of the page. I originally said I could help thinking it was an easy fix, but I really don't know what's going on.

I've tried using preventDefault on clicks to the images, I've tried looking into the basic documentation for the plugin and messing with the parameters passed in, but to no luck.

I realize that this is not a lot for you all to work with, but on the off chance that someone has had this problem before or just someone knows a possible solution, please let me know!

Thanks!

Edit: I simplified the page down to one image so you can see the jump that takes place easier.

Answer (score 0):

Return false from the event handlers.

Comment: `preventDefault()` should do the same and work better in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Google turned up this link: http://flipgallery.net/fliplightbox.html

If that's the plugin which you use, then try the latest version and compare your code to the one in the demo - the demo doesn't scroll.

Comment: Sorry I should've included this link: http://jpinghu.com/fliplightboxjs

And I don't have access to the code for that but even in the demo for that the demo doesn't scroll so I'm wondering if it's the layout of the page or if the minified js behind it has some errors

Comment: First step is always to make sure you use the latest version. Did you check this?

Comment: I just have the minified code but the original coder told me that he purchased the script within the last couple weeks so it is up to date

Comment: Okay. So here is a trick which might help: You could install an `onscroll` event handler (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll) to log when the window is scrolled. The next step is then to add logging in a couple of places in the code to see in which order things happen. That should help you to narrow it down. Also, if he bought the script, then there should be some support. If you can't figure it out, ask them to have a look.